# Laravel When clicked on button with a question on it, a input will appear with the question pre filled in

Tags: html, laravel, database

First of all i am pretty much a beginner to programming, so im sorry if i didn't explain it well. In my database i have stored over 30 questions, with 2 table names called '`vraag`' (questions) and '`antwoorden`'(answers). I display all the '`vraag`'(questions) as a button seperately. When i click on the button there appears a popup menu with a few input fields. That'll look like this: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAAeg.png)

the menu on the right is the menu that pops up when a button is clicked. The thing what i want to do is that when a question has been clicked, it doesn't matter which one. That the clicked `question` is pre filled in the input field under the "`Vraag`" which is in my code "`inpt4`". With my code now it only shows the first question, no matter which question i click on, instead of every question different. Here is my code:

```
<div class="vragen">                                                                             
    @foreach ($vragen as $vraag)
    <br>
        <br> 
            <button type="submit" class="{{ $vraag["class"] }}" onclick="openPopup()">{{ $vraag["omschrijving"] }}</button>
    @endforeach
</div>

@foreach($vragen as $vraag)
<div class="popup" id="popup">

<!--<div class="id">
        <label for="">ID</label>
    </div> -->

    <div class="antwoord">
        <label for="">Antwoorden</label>
    </div>
 
    <div class="vraag">
        <label for="">Vraag</label>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="vvid">
        <label for="">Volgende Vraag ID</label>
    </div>

    <div class="inpt1">
        <input type="text" value="">
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="inpt2">
        <input type="text" name="name">
    </div>

    <div class="inpt3">
        <input type="button" onclick="closePopup()" value="Opslaan"/>
    </div>

    <div class="inpt4">
        <input type="text" value="{{ $vraag["omschrijving"] }}">
    </div>

    <div class="inpt5">
        <input type="text" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="inpt6">
        <input type="text" name="name">
    </div>

</div>

@endforeach
```

Comment: `id` attributes _must_ be unique. Yours aren't. Also maybe make your button `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`

Comment: does it make a difference when i change my button to type="button"?

Comment: `type="submit"` would submit a form (if you had one). `type="button"` is just a button with no default behaviour, and does nothing when pressed. Doesn't really make a difference here